# instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier show blank view (xcode 4.5)

Tags: iphone, ios, storyboard, ios6

I heard that in XCode 4.5 there's some changes that the Storyboard identifier is no longer called identifier but Storyboard ID. I tried to use it but it doesn't initiate anything. It's always blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
 UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];

 HistoryViewController* historyVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"histSB"];
```

With

```
  [self presentViewController:historyVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

OR

```
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:historyVC animated:YES];
```

OR

```
 [self presentModalViewController:historyVC animated:YES];
```

See screenshot for settings in storyboard:

[image]

Comment: So you have a second storyboard-file called `Storyboard.storyboard` besides the standard `MainStoryboard.storyboard`?

Comment: So I only have one...and that's what I called it. (That was before I realized there was a convention on naming. But beside this, the storyboard is loading fine.)

Comment: If you have only one then your parent VC is defined in the same SB. In this case you could instead use `self.storyboard`, which I use all the time without an issue. If this doesn't work either, probably there is sth. about your VC-implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I use a few times in my app for those places were segues are impractical.  Going from the code and screen shot provided above, here's how I'd wire it up:

```
HistoryViewController *historyVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"histSB"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: historyVC animated:YES];
```

This is particularly useful if you're displaying your view controller from a popopver on iPad.  Add the view with its own navigation controller to the storyboard:

[image]

Notice that there's no segue coming in to the left side of the navigation controller.  The following code displays this in the popover:

```
HistoryViewController *historyVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"histSB"];
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: historyVC];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController: navigationController];
```

You can then use this as a basis for pushing other view controllers onto the navigation controller via a segue (notice the one to the right side of the view controller):

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"WhateverComesNextSegue" sender: self];
```

Hope that helps.